# How do I test my Phonegap app with a wamp server locally?

Tags: cordova, dreamweaver, wampserver, phonegap-plugins

I have a Dreamweaver site which works succesfully on my Chrome browser, but I want to test it against an Android emulator. As of date, I have been able to build and emulate my dreamweaver site through (site->configure framework) but I am having difficulties making Ajax calls to my localserver where my php services are (which is Wampserver). When I click a button wired to make an Ajax call, nothing happens.

One thing to note is I have WAMP succesfully installed and my application works well in the chrome browser. The question is what am I really doing wrong?

Is it that Phonegap cannot connect to local servers?

Below is my block of code that makes the Ajax call:

```
$('form#TSLogin').bind('submit',function() {
  var u=  $('#TsUsername').val();
  var p=  $('#TsPassword').val();
  $.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:"/services/login.php",
    dataType:"json",
    data:$("form#TSLogin").serialize(),
    success:function(data){
      if (data.errora==true){
        alert("chima");
      }
      if (data.errora==false){
        alert("failed");
      }
    }
  });
  return false;
});
```

What am I doing wrong, or what am I not doing yet? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In this case you should use jsonp instead of json

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to replace:
`url:"/services/login.php",` by `url:"http://yourAddressIp/services/login.php",`

Answer (score 0):

try the android emulator url

```
url = "http://10.0.2.2/yourfile.php"
```